# Permission Set assignment for Chatter Free and Chatter Free External Profile failed. (Partner Community - Learning Purpose)

Tags: chatter, permission-sets

When i figured that i can't give access to "Edit my own posts and comments" via profile (Chatter Free and External) I tried the same from permission set. But it too failed saying "Failure : Can't complete this operation because it would exceed the number of apps allowed by the user license.". But there were no assigned apps as such.

Is there a way to escape this? or its a voluntary limitation? if so I would like to hear about reasons why.

PS: This is purely for learning purpose and I am a novice when it comes to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is not escape to this
2. These are part of the users license restriction setup by Salesforce
3. For additional licenses kindly contact salesforce and they will provide an additional set of licenses
4. Either change the license and the profile on the user to access chatter.

Comment: Thank you @Meghesh